# Como interromper a execução do each do jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com um problema ao percorrer rows (de uma DIV que está dentro de outra DIV) com o método `each`.

Quando uma condição é verdadeira, eu preciso interromper o *loop* e exibir uma mensagem para o usuário, mas não estou conseguindo interrompê-lo.

Pesquisei na net, e descobri que o `each` tem esse problema, mas só encontrei soluções usando o `for` e eu não sei como transformar minha estrutura atual de `each` para `for`. Alguém sabe me ajudar com isso ou oferecer alguma solução para interromper o laço `each`?

```
var rowPessoaAnaliseCredito = $(this).closest('.row-pessoa-analise-credito');

$(rowPessoaAnaliseCredito).find('.row-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta').each(function (indiceJ, elemento) {
    if ($(elemento).find('.sel-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta-orgao-protecao-credito').val() === '') 
        return;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

> *You can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning `false`.*

Ou seja, basta que a função de *callback* retorne `false`.

Segue abaixo uma comparação do seu código (adaptado porque não foi fornecido o HTML), e a diferença quando o retorno é `false`:

```js
// imprime "abc" e "def"
console.log('each percorre todos');
$('#analise-credito').find('.row-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta').each(function (indiceJ, elemento) {
    var valor = $(elemento).find('.sel-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta-orgao-protecao-credito').val();
    if (valor === '') {
        return; // <-- esse return não interrompe o each
    } else {
        console.log(`achei: ${valor}`);
    }
});

// imprime somente "abc"
console.log('--------\neach para no primeiro vazio que encontrar');
$('#analise-credito').find('.row-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta').each(function (indiceJ, elemento) {
    var valor = $(elemento).find('.sel-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta-orgao-protecao-credito').val();
    if (valor === '') {
        return false; // <-- retorna false para interromper o each
    } else {
        console.log(`achei: ${valor}`);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="analise-credito">
  <p class="row-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta">
    <input type="text" class="sel-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta-orgao-protecao-credito" value="abc">
  </p>
  <p class="row-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta">
    <input type="text" class="sel-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta-orgao-protecao-credito" value="">  </p>
  <p class="row-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta">
    <input type="text" class="sel-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta-orgao-protecao-credito" value="def">  </p>
</div>
```

Ou seja, no primeiro caso ele percorre todos os elementos (imprimindo todos os não-vazios - no caso, "abc" e "def"). E no segundo caso, ele interrompe quando o primeiro vazio for encontrado, então só imprime o "abc".

---

A opção com `for` é sem jQuery, bastando usar [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) e [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) para buscar os elementos que você precisa:

```js
for (const elemento of document.querySelectorAll('.row-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta')) {
    var valor = elemento.querySelector('.sel-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta-orgao-protecao-credito').value;
    if (valor === '') {
        break; // interrompe o for
    } else {
        console.log(`achei: ${valor}`);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="analise-credito">
  <p class="row-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta">
    <input type="text" class="sel-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta-orgao-protecao-credito" value="abc">
  </p>
  <p class="row-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta">
    <input type="text" class="sel-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta-orgao-protecao-credito" value="">  </p>
  <p class="row-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta">
    <input type="text" class="sel-pessoa-analise-credito-consulta-orgao-protecao-credito" value="def">  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado @hkotsubo!!!! O problema estava em eu retornar com "return". Ao retornar com "return false", deu certo. :)